# How to create a custom date period slicer Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a slicer that will allow me to filter based on custom date groupings of Last 7 days, Last 30 days, Last 60 days, etc..  I found the below logic in another thread which seems to be exactly what I need.  However when I see the results the dates do not correspond with the output I am expecting (see screenshot). For example I am showing 2/1/2024 showing up in the Last 7 days and last 30 days.  I created a calculated table with this logic and linked it to a calendar table in my dashboard.  I also tested the logic using single and bi-directional cross filter and nothing is working.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
Date Periods = 
UNION(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(TODAY() - 7, TODAY()),
        "Period", "Last 7 days",
        "Sort", 1
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(TODAY() - 30, TODAY()),
        "Period", "Last 30 days",
        "Sort", 2
    ),
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR(TODAY() - 60, TODAY()),
        "Period", "Last 60 days",
        "Sort", 3
    )
)
```

I created a calculated table with this logic and linked it to a calendar table in my dashboard.  I also tested the logic using single and bi-directional cross filter and nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `Date` column is set to Data type `Date` and not `DateTime`.

Comment: Good catch on the data type. When I change the data type to match I still get dates that are not showing the correct period.  I show 1/21/24 showing last 60 days and 1/21/24 showing last 30 days. I also show some dates being duplicated with two different periods. For example 1/7/24 is showing last 30 days and last 60 days. Could the time still be impacting this?  Or is the logic flawed in someway? Thanks.

Comment: 1/21/24 is within 60 days, and 30 days - what am I missing? What is the issue? And help clarify if it is in `Date Periods` or in `Calendar`.